# How to make buttons invisible with swift code on Xcode 7?

Tags: swift, uibutton, xcode7

I put some buttons in a game on SpriteKit using Xcode 7 Beta, they stay all the time visible and I wanted to make them invisible when game is started and visible when game is over. I tried with Bool but it won't work because they are in different files (classes). Function to start game and to over it is in GameScene.swift, and functions of buttons are in GameViewController.swift.

Code that I used game to start is:

```
var isStarted = false


func start() {
    isStarted = true
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    if isGameOver {
        restart()
    } else !isStarted {
        start()
```

So the game starts at touch on screen.

Code that I used game to over is:

```
var isGameOver = false

func gameOver() {
    isGameOver = true
}
```

And buttons are in GameViewController.swift as sender: UIButton.

```
@IBAction func facebookShare(sender: UIButton){
    let facebookShare : SLComposeViewController = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook)
    self.presentViewController(facebookShare, animated: true, completion: nil)
}



@IBAction func twitterShare(sender: UIButton) {
    let twitterShare : SLComposeViewController = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeTwitter)
    self.presentViewController(twitterShare, animated: true, completion: nil)
}



@IBAction func leaderboard(sender: UIButton) {

}



@IBAction func removeAds(sender: UIButton) {

}
```

As You see I didn't finished two more buttons, anyway I will after this.
I hope You will be helpful because I'm beginner

Comment: What exactly do you want? You want to hide a Button thats property of another class's UIView? Because you can hide a button like yourButton.hidden = true

Comment: It's not possible to hide it so I tried, func start() {
isStarted = true
facebookShare.hidden = true
}
but won't work !

Comment: Well I guess I understand your problem, I will write you an short answer and hope that I understand you right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, below you will find a way how to send an event to any Object that is listening to it....

```
class ClassWithButtonsInIt: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonOne: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonTwo: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonThree: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("hideButtonsEvent"), name: "hideButtonsEvent", object: nil)
    }

    deinit {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
    }

    private func hideButtonsEvent (notification: NSNotification) {
        buttonOne.hidden = true
        buttonTwo.hidden = true
        buttonThree.hidden = true
    }
}

class ClassWithoutButtonsThatTriggersTheHidingEvent {

    private func triggerdFunctionThatHidesButtonsInOtherClass () {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("hideButtonsEvent", object: nil)
    }

}
```

**EDIT**

Yes thats right, sorry I had a little bug in my Code too :-)
Please change this line:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("hideButtonsEvent"), name: "hideButtonsEvent", object: nil)
```

To this line (see the double dot behind hideButtonsEvent):

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("hideButtonsEvent:"), name: "hideButtonsEvent", object: nil)
```

And this line:

```
private func hideButtonsEvent (notification: NSNotification) {
```

To this line (delete the private modifier):

```
func hideButtonsEvent (notification: NSNotification) {
```

Comment: Does that make sense to you? Do you understand whats happening?

Comment: I tried to do something but won't work, deinit {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
    }
    
    private func hideButtonsEvent (notification: NSNotification) {
        facebookButton.hidden = true
        twitterButton.hidden = true
        leaderboardButton.hidden = true
        removeAdsButton.hidden = true
    }

I think code above is not good ! check it if is it ok.
and NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("hideButtonsEvent", object: nil), I put it in func start() but when I load game and tap in game to start it found error

Comment: here is error:

2015-08-17 19:22:16.928 Squares[10397:699787] -[Squares.GameViewController hideButtonsEvent]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe3b41314c0
2015-08-17 19:22:16.933 Squares[10397:699787] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Squares.GameViewController hideButtonsEvent]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe3b41314c0'
*** First throw call stack:
(

Comment: 0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106366885 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001068a8df1 objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010636eb5d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
3   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001062bbe3a 
___forwarding___ + 970
4   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001062bb9e8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
5   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010633359c 
__CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 12

Comment: Hi Emin, sorry I had a little bug in my code too :-) I have posted you an update with the changes in it

Comment: It's working my friend but please add this to answer because other users to see, It needs to add func to be shown buttons again, like this one

func showButtonsEvent (notification: NSNotification) {
        facebookButton.hidden = false
        twitterButton.hidden = false
        leaderboardButton.hidden = false
        removeAdsButton.hidden = false
    }
 NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("showButtonsEvent", object: nil)